# Set Constraints Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, label, constraints

I am trying to add an UIView with a label, and want to set constraints to place the label in the center horizontally as well as vertically. But the code doesn't place it as I want. Below is the code. The label is presented on the top left hand corner of the screen instead of the center of the screen.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var title = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func presentTitle ()

    }

    func presentTitle () {
        title.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        title.textColor = UIColor.white
        title.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 30)
        title.textAlignment = .center
        title.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        title.numberOfLines = 1
        title..text = vmTitleTransferredFromTaskAnalysisDetail!
        self.view.addSubview(title)

        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        title.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        title.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        title.eadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.view = title
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `self.view = title`.

Comment: Thanks, Maddy! It works. By the way, what is the function of self.view = title? if your time permit, please answer :)

Comment: That line replaces the view controller's view with your `title` label making your label the only view in the entire view controller.